# How to use grep -v 'username}|^$' in shell script where it is failing with user=username}|\E[31m^': command not found

Tags: shell, unix

I have to ignore the lines ending with "user=username}|^" these strings .

Sample lines :

```
^2019-11-30T12:20:23Z|||{node=adfasjdfklaj|step=1|stepctx=1|user=username}|^
^2019-11-30T12:19:21Z||| 
{node=adfasjdfklaj|step=1|stepctx=1|user=username}|CLEANUP................ PENDING^
```

I m using the

```
"grep -v 'username}|^$'"
```

at command line it is working fine , but when I am using the same in the **shell script** complaining about the below error .

```
user=username}|\E[31m^': command not found
```

How to handle this situation?

Comment: The error looks like you have unpaired quote somewhere earlier in your script, but this is very speculative.

Comment: Please post MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use Windows EOL (End Of Line) in the script. What you can do is to convert the script in UNIX/Linux EOL:

```
dos2unix your_script_name
```

or

```
d2u your_script_name
```

Comment: dos2unix wont work for me on this file  as [username]$ dos2unix 17xyz.log
dos2unix: Binary symbol found at line 13
dos2unix: Skipping binary file 17xyz.log

Comment: @ranganathnangineni, apply to the script, not the log

Comment: Even dos2unix with -f the file conversion is not happening. So I have to deal with the  "^" sign in the shell script.